# Ideas to visualise historical map data/transportation/logistics/scheduled events?

Tags: visualization

I have many data points which span over a decade and they look similar to this:

[image]

Maybe someone has some cool interactive and/or not interactive ideas on nice representations of such data? I was thinking of visualizing the data on the map, but I feel like maybe this is too boring (see the image below for reference).

I think it would be smart to show the historical traveling locations (At first Vehicle1 was at 14,83, then the same Vehicle1 moved to 14,84 ...), but if I have many points nearby and they stay around, it may overcrowd my visualizations.

I'd appreciate any ideas or libraries to show this.

[image]